# Http session encryption in ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using session Id in HTTPsession in ASP.NET Core 5.0:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("CompanyID", Convert.ToString(session.CompanyID));
```

Do I need to encrypt my `id` or will it get encrypted internally?

My `id` is kind of sensitive one and I want to use that id further in application.

Is my approach safe or not?

My edited code for more clarification

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Index([Bind] LoginModel loginModel)
{
  SessionModels session = new SessionModels();
  session =  //getting data from database 
   HttpContext.Session.SetString("CompanyID", 
   Convert.ToString(session.CompanyID));
 }

 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult MyAction(InternalModel internal )
 {

 string strCompanyID= HttpContext.Session.GetString("CompanyID");
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCompanyID= ))
 {
                       ////
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session is stored serverside, the client gets a cookie with a random session ID. Session data is not shown to the user unless you display it somewher.

But:

> My id is kind of sensitive one and I want to use that id further in application. My approach is safe or not?

No. Sounds like you're using security through obscurity. You need to verify on every request that does something with a CompanyID that the logged in user is allowed to access that company's resources.

Comment: I don't get it. How can I verify that. I'm simply accessing/getting session data by using HttpContext.Session.Getstring. Please guide me on this one.

Comment: I can't guide you on code you don't show.

Comment: Ok wait i will edit my code .

Comment: I edited Code. hope this will enough to understand my query.

Comment: The session part of your question is answered by the first half of my answer. I then explain why you should not keep your IDs secret, but use authorization instead (which user can do what).